# Display the customer's title column on a Magento PDF invoice

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to modify the Print PDF output in my Magento admin interface to display the customer's title. This is already working to display the name:

```
$this->getCustomer()->getName()
```

The programmer who worked on this site before me had the following inserted:

```
$this->getOrder()->getBillingAddress()->getTitle()
```

However, that was not displaying the correct title. I am looking for the title which is stored with the Default Contact Address, which is apparently not the billing address.

I also tried this (just a guess, as it seemed obvious), but it is not working either:

```
$this->getCustomer()->getTitle()
```

I can see the data in the database, just not sure how to grab it from my header.phtml file?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you want `getPrefix()`: http://www.kathirvel.com/magento-get-loggedin-customer-fullname-firstname-lastname-email-address/

Comment: $this->getCustomer()->getPrefix() doesn't return anything, unfortunately. Also, I'm not looking for the prefix column, I'm looking for the customer's title (the prefix appears to be NULL in the database).